# How to hide horizontal monotonic sequence of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

My input is `df` :

```
   COLUMN_1  COLUMN_2  COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
0         0         1         0         2
1         1         1         2         3
2         1         2         3         2
3         1         2         4         5
4         4         5         8         8
```

And I wish I can hide (horizontally, from left to the non inclusive right) monotonic sequences with a difference equal to 1. For example if in a row we have `[4, 5, 8, 8]` (like in the last one), the concerned sequence is `[4, 5)`. So, we need to hide the number `4` with an emty string.

My expected output is this :

```
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
0                 1        0         2
1        1                           3
2                          3         2
3                 2                  5
4                 5        8         8
```

Explanation :

[image]

I tried with the code below but I'm not in the right track since I get a weird boolean dataframe.

```
df.diff(axis=1).eq(1).iloc[:, ::-1].cummax(axis=1).replace(True, '').iloc[:, ::-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative period in [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), combined with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
out = df.mask(df.diff(-1, axis=1).eq(-1), '')
```

or, for in place modification:

```
df[df.eq(df.shift(-1, axis=1)-1)] = ''
```

Variant with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
out = df.mask(df.eq(df.shift(-1, axis=1)-1), '')
```

Output:

```
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
0                 1        0         2
1        1                           3
2                          3         2
3                 2                  5
4                 5        8         8
```

Intermediates:

```
# df.diff(-1, axis=1)
   COLUMN_1  COLUMN_2  COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
0        -1         1        -2       NaN
1         0        -1        -1       NaN
2        -1        -1         1       NaN
3        -1        -2        -1       NaN
4        -1        -3         0       NaN

# df.shift(-1, axis=1)
   COLUMN_1  COLUMN_2  COLUMN_3  COLUMN_4
0         1         0         2       NaN
1         1         2         3       NaN
2         2         3         2       NaN
3         2         4         5       NaN
4         5         8         8       NaN
```

Comment: You made the solution of my problem looks obvious. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'COLUMN_1': [0, 1, 1, 1, 4],
    'COLUMN_2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 5],
    'COLUMN_3': [0, 2, 3, 4, 8],
    'COLUMN_4': [2, 3, 2, 5, 8]
})

df = df.astype(str)  # Convert DataFrame to string type

for col in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    mask = (df.iloc[:, col] == df.iloc[:, col-1].astype(int).add(1).astype(str))
    df.iloc[:, col-1] = df.iloc[:, col-1].where(~mask, '')
df.head()
```

Output

```
  COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3 COLUMN_4
0                 1        0        2
1        1                          3
2                          3        2
3                 2                 5
4                 5        8        8
```

- It uses a boolean `mask` to identify the elements that need to be replaced with an empty string. It also avoids unnecessary iterations over rows by using vectorized operations.
- iterates over each column (from the second column) and creates a boolean mask, that identifies the elements that need to be replaced. It then uses the `where` method to replace the elements in the previous column with an empty string where the mask is `True`.